# comment resolu problem sql.java.sql.SQLException

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-8

```
private void totaleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
     PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rst;
 String query="SELECT SUM( montant_m)  FROM `mnd` ";
   String num_m = jTF1.getText();
    try {
        ps=Connecteur_db.connecterDB().prepareStatement(query);
        // ps.setString(1, num_m);
         rst=ps.executeQuery();
         if(rst.next()){
            String som_t = rst.getString("SUM(montant_m)");
           jLabe_resultat.setText(""+som_t);
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+som_t);
          }
         } catch (SQLException ex) {            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(noveau_j.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
      }
```

While trying to execute this i am getting an error like "Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'SUM(montant_m)' not found.
    at  What is the problem here?? Please help me..
Sorry for my poor english
This is myconnecteur_db() class the connection

```
public static Connection connecterDB() {
    Connection conx = null;
    String pilot = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    try {
        Class.forName(pilot);//chargement de driver
        System.out.println("Driver ok");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/tc";
        String user = "root";
        String pw;
        pw = "root";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pw);
        System.out.println("la connection est bien etablir");
        return con;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Echec connection!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is occuring at the line `rst.getString("SUM(montant_m)")`

`SUM(montant_m)` doesn't have a space before `montant_m`.

To make it easier, use the query:

```
SELECT SUM(montant_m) AS total FROM mnd
```

And then `rst.getString("total")`

Comment: hi thanks for your help 
sum here is double i do this code and run 
'double som_t = rst.getdouble(1);'